# E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, updates, steam

Hello i recently tried to install steam on ubuntu on 64-bit desktop version didn't work ,so i tried server version 64-bit still didn't work. I saw somebody say that steam is only 32-bit so i tried 32-bit server version but still got same result.

I use  Raspberry Pi 4 Model B; 4 GB, ARM-Cortex-A72 4 x, 1.50 GHz, 4 GB RAM.

```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  steam-devices

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate
```

so i tried this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/958965/1185248
didn't work

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

i am stuck here a don't know what to do.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: There are many sites with this info here is one of them https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: How to install steam on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: this isn't as simple as adding x86 repository, and in the end these games are compiled for x86_64 linux architecture and are not meant to run in aarch64 linux architecture, for now.