# Unable to install steam on Ubuntu running in parallels on my M1

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, games, steam

I tried following the guide as per [lubuntu installing steam "steam has no installation candidate"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958957/lubuntu-installing-steam-steam-has-no-installation-candidate/958965#958965)

But the error message I get is as below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  steam-devices

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate
```

system is fully up to date, upgraded etc, still no idea what I should do, or if steam is supported yet?

Comment: The `steam` package is in the `multiverse` pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. Do you have that pocket enabled? If you are unsure how to find out, then [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1453785/edit) to include the complete output of the command `sudo apt update`

Comment: You've not provided your OS/release detail, so a CLI query I performed as reading your question allows me to see what versions/releases the package is available for; are you using one of those? as you didn't tell us your OS/release details; are we to guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Ubuntu in a VM on an M1 mac means you won't be able to install Steam due to you running the arm64 architecture. There's no arm64 build of steam - and indeed no arm64 build of any of the games inside steam.

Steam requires an Intel/AMD (AMD64 / x86_64) CPU, not an ARM based M1 processor in your Mac.